# Complex Event Processing-Stream Processing

Tags: apache-storm, complex-event-processing, esper

I am trying to learn how Esper collaborates with Storm.I am having a look at Esper's source code because i want to find out where data is stored by Esper(tables,arrays etc).For example when esper receives a stream of tuples and an event type is declared,how is this data stored by Esper (source code);When a query is executed how is the data results stored etc?I want to find where all these happen in Esper's source code.Any help is most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Esper's data structures reflect the EPL statement.

This stores nothing:

```
select * from MyEvent
```

This stores a long-type count only:

```
select count(*) from MyEvent
```

This stores a count and total:

```
select avg(field) from MyEvent
```

This stores a count per groupfield:

```
select count(*) from MyEvent group by groupfield
```

This stores the last 5 events:

```
select * from MyEvent.win:length(5)
```

Patterns have their own data structures, so does each data window and match-recognize etc.. Indexes for joins and such are also data structures. I'm afraid there is no single code location but many and there is no single data structure but many different specialized ones.